Nullpointer in Hibernate 6.4 criteria query
I've upgraded hibernate from 5.3.28 to 6.4.4 and I found a strange null pointer exception while before it worked.
The following is the DAO method raising the npe, on equal condition:
public AuditAction findAction(Long organizationId, String actionClass, String actionName) throws Exception {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<AuditAction> criteria = builder.createQuery(AuditAction.class);
        Root<AuditAction> root = criteria.from(AuditAction.class);

        Predicate filter = builder.equal(root.get(AuditAction_.organization), organizationId);
        filter = builder.and(filter, builder.equal(root.get(AuditAction_.actionClassName), actionClass));
        filter = builder.and(filter, builder.equal(root.get(AuditAction_.actionName), actionName));
        criteria.where(filter);

        TypedQuery<AuditAction> q = createQuery(criteria);
        List<AuditAction> results = q.getResultList();
        return results != null && results.size() > 0 ? results.get(0) : null;
}

The error is the following:
Audit error!: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "value" is null
    at org.hibernate@6.4.4.Final//org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.EntityJavaType.isInstance(EntityJavaType.java:56)
    at org.hibernate@6.4.4.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.isInstance(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:1814)
    at org.hibernate@6.4.4.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.valueParameter(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:1856)
    at org.hibernate@6.4.4.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.value(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:1785)
    at org.hibernate@6.4.4.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.equal(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:2131)
    at org.hibernate@6.4.4.Final//org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.equal(SqmCriteriaNodeBuilder.java:192)
    at deployment.HIS.war//it.gpi.his.be.ejb.entities.audit.dao.AuditActionDao.findActiveAction(AuditActionDao.java:72)
    at deployment.HIS.war//it.gpi.his.be.ejb.sessions.AuditSessionBean.handleAuditMessage(AuditSessionBean.java:327)

Any idea?
I search online documentation to find breaking changes, but I didn't found anything

Did you find a solution? builder.equal() previously worked when receiving null values but now it throws a NPE
